# Git command that shows changed revisions and files based on a file pattern

Tags: bash, git

I would like to find a convenient way to list revisions that contain changes to a particular file pattern (say, `pom.xml`) and lists commit message and changed files.

Is there something out of the box, or will I need to first scan the history using something like:

```
git rev-list --all -- 'pom.xml'
```

And the go over each of the revisions one by one to list the changed files?

Comment: I suggest you use `find` to find the files you want, then supply it to `git` with command substitution (`git ... $(find ...`) or , my preference for good handling of whitespace in filenames, `find  ... -print0 | xargs -0 git ref-list -- `

Comment: @erik258 : This is not a viable solution, because it will look for files are exist in your current revision and will then look for them historically. It will not cover files that have been deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git rev-list` is lower-level than that, `git log` has a lot of handy conveniences wrapped around it, like diving into analyzing the effects of commits, for instance what files they changed:

```
git log --pretty=%H -- \*.xml
```

or

```
git log --pretty=%H -m --first-parent -- \*.xml
```

to analyze merges for their net effects rather than chasing through each merged commit. separately.

> and lists commit message and changed files.

then you *really* want `git log`.

```
git log -m --first-parent --name-only --full-diff -- \*.xml
```

from comments: to paste the commit id on the front of the changed files just use awk, it's built for that. IRL it's down in true oneliner territory but broken out for didactic digestibility it's

```
git log -m --first-parent --pretty=format:%H --name-only --full-diff -- \*.xml \
| awk '!NF  { id=""; next }
       !id  { id=$0; next }
       { print id,$0 }
'
```

Comment: This is great! Could it print something like `$revision: $relativePath`?

Comment: For that you want to do some `awk` postprocessing, to append the id to the front of each path, it's not hard.

Comment: This seems to be always printing the same revision. It's also not grepping for a path pattern. If you could improve this, it would be great! :)

Comment: How exactly the notion that `del` would unset an awk variable snuck in on me I have no idea. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

START_COMMIT=${1:-$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)}
END_COMMIT=${2:-$(git rev-parse HEAD)}
echo "Searching for changes to pom.xml files between $START_COMMIT and $END_COMMIT"

for commit in $(git rev-list $START_COMMIT..$END_COMMIT)
do
    if git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $commit | grep -q "pom.xml"; then
        git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $commit | grep "pom.xml" | while read file; do
            echo "$commit: $file"
        done
        echo ""
    fi
done
```

It will print out:

```
Searching for changes to pom.xml files between 5feff7ed67b2245173973d8057b7d434863a031a and cfc3d544fb8209c55a41f87aa652b488e05423a3
4fb99107e944f151dcdee9636122d6b9579ce993: data/pom.xml
4fb99107e944f151dcdee9636122d6b9579ce993: pom.xml
4fb99107e944f151dcdee9636122d6b9579ce993: webapp/pom.xml

c3032fee2389329d5914d38b13e8f42e453439a3: webapp/pom.xml

e062ac683089b221c3f156865dd9ecf5ee35edae: webapp/pom.xml

fd60a897548d41f20374f0059b42848e028cbd78: pom.xml

6fdd2bd57ff2145ad1f88bda7f51093a93147d06: data/pom.xml
6fdd2bd57ff2145ad1f88bda7f51093a93147d06: pom.xml

f0349f63d466c11c2d2d11c2322d94f78646bd93: data/pom.xml
f0349f63d466c11c2d2d11c2322d94f78646bd93: webapp/pom.xml

19137762ca2dbe223c7139bd13c1c236839a807a: pom.xml
19137762ca2dbe223c7139bd13c1c236839a807a: webapp/pom.xml

6ad48fcbb8491a67fb10d2ffe39f1afc7005f11f: webapp/pom.xml

83fe9740d3790eb700082f09c6ff7c8d8635f4dd: webapp/pom.xml

d597001c54d980ad03b08b8bfd758eabc3c82ea6: webapp/pom.xml

e0b132884bda2645a7b3b597b5778b48ea4c6bc7: data/pom.xml
e0b132884bda2645a7b3b597b5778b48ea4c6bc7: pom.xml
e0b132884bda2645a7b3b597b5778b48ea4c6bc7: webapp/pom.xml
```

Comment: I am quite sure you're right. It's room for improvement. In this case it's a quick and dirty solution for a repository that doesn't have a huge history or number of files. So it would do the job. If you would like to update your answer with this, then that would be great for anybody looking for a similar solutioni n the future.